# Is it possible to create, update, delete the events on Google Calendar application with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar

Is it possible to implement this functionalities synchronously with Google Calendar, and it will be reflected on Google Calendar immediately?

Create a new calendar event in the chosen calendar
Update an existing calendar event, by UID, in the chosen calendar
Delete a calendar event, by UID, on the chosen calendar
The above functionality should work on Android and iOS

Actually, I tried [syncfusion_flutter_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar), but I think it is working as a view only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use their API:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/overview

Also, it is not free.

Comment: In this case, I think right now there is no written SDK for this purpose, right?

Comment: Another case is that, it can be implemented with backend developer,